# Sending JSON request with Spray IO Client

Tags: json, scala, io, spray

Right now I'm building an small API in Scala that uses the Spray.IO Framework to handle the requests & responses.

When my /update URL is called I want to call another API to process the actual update, along with this request I want to add some JSON data.

For this I use the following code:

```
  val message: String = "{\"elements\":[{\"id\":\"2\",\"attributes\":[{\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"float\",\"value\":\"46\"}]}],\"updateAction\":\"UPDATE\"}"
  val url: String = "http://[domain]/update"

  val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive
  val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(
    Post(url, message)
      ~> addHeaders(List(
        RawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    ))
  )

  response onComplete { completedResponse =>
    println("Response: "+completedResponse.get.message.entity.asString)
  }
```

But when I check the logs I can see that the Content-Type actually get sets to `text/plain; charset=UTF-8`, this happens because of the Spray IO Client actually determines the Content-Type itself.

So my question here is; how can i get Spray IO to actually recognize my message as `Content-Type:application/json`..

Any thoughts? Would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create HttpEntity with proper ContentType:

```
Post(url, HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, message))
```

This thing explained in docs http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-http/#content-type-header